# Why the state of the duration is all the time 7 even if updating the state inside the while in the ienumerator?

Tags: unity, c#

I want to get the current coroutine state.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.PostProcessing;


public class DepthOfField : MonoBehaviour
{
    public UnityEngine.GameObject player;
    public PostProcessingProfile postProcessingProfile;
    public bool dephOfFieldFinished = false;
    public LockSystem playerLockMode;

    private Animator playerAnimator;
    private float clipLength;
    private Coroutine depthOfFieldRoutineRef;
    private DepthOfFieldModel.Settings depthOfField;
    private DepthField state;

    void Start()
    {
        if (depthOfFieldRoutineRef != null)
        {
            StopCoroutine(depthOfFieldRoutineRef);
        }

        playerAnimator = player.GetComponent<Animator>();

        AnimationClip[] clips = playerAnimator.runtimeAnimatorController.animationClips;
        foreach (AnimationClip clip in clips)
        {
            clipLength = clip.length;
        }

        DepthOfFieldInit(clipLength);

        state = new DepthField();
    }

    public void DepthOfFieldInit(float duration)
    {
        depthOfField = postProcessingProfile.depthOfField.settings;
        depthOfField.focalLength = 300;
        StartCoroutine(changeValueOverTime(depthOfField.focalLength, 1, duration));
        postProcessingProfile.depthOfField.settings = depthOfField;
    }

    public IEnumerator changeValueOverTime(float fromVal, float toVal, float duration)
    {
        playerLockMode.PlayerLockState(true, true);

        float counter = 0f;

        while (counter < duration)
        {
            var dof = postProcessingProfile.depthOfField.settings;

            counter += Time.deltaTime;

            float val = Mathf.Lerp(fromVal, toVal, counter / duration);

            dof.focalLength = val;
            postProcessingProfile.depthOfField.settings = dof;

            state.duration = duration;
            state.focalLength = val;

            yield return null;
        }

        playerAnimator.enabled = false;
        dephOfFieldFinished = true;
        depthOfFieldRoutineRef = null;
    }

    public struct DepthField
    {
        public float focalLength;
        public float duration;
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        SaveGame.Save("depthoffieldstate", state);
    }

    public void Load()
    {
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
        depthOfField = postProcessingProfile.depthOfField.settings;
        DepthField state = SaveGame.Load<DepthField>("depthoffieldstate");
        depthOfField.focalLength = state.focalLength;
        StartCoroutine(changeValueOverTime(depthOfField.focalLength, 1, state.duration));
        postProcessingProfile.depthOfField.settings = depthOfField;
    }
}
```

Inside the while loop I'm doing :

```
state.duration = duration;
state.focalLength = val;
```

The focalLength value does change if for example I save onethe game start the focalLength value will be 299 and if I will save after the coroutine has finished the focalLength value is 1.

But the coroutine duration value is not changing it keep staying on 7 when saving even if the coroutine has finished and should be 0 it still 7.

The value 7 of the duration is coming from the clipLength.

1. I can't get the current duration time of the coroutine.
2. In the Load function I'm starting the coroutine over again but since I'm using the loaded focalLength value and duration value it should look like the coroutine is continue from the last saved point. But I can't get the correct duration value when saving.

Comment: Did you mean to save/load the *remaining* duration, rather than the total? The total duration will not change no matter how long the coroutine has run in your current code, only the counter changes, and it looks like you don't save/load the counter.

Comment: @DMGregory Yes I mean the remaining duration. Yeah then I'm doing it wrong.